# proper usage of makefile

Tags: c++, compilation, makefile

So, I'm trying to understand makefiles. At this moment I have a project with some modules, which are more or less non-dependent on each others.

My directory tree is like this:

```
root/
- Source/ <-- referenced as $(INPUTPATH)
- Build/ <-- referenced as $(BUILDPATH)
- Release/ <-- referenced as $(OUTPUTPATH)
- Makefile
```

I want to have the source (*.cpp/*.h) on the Source/, the objects on the Build/, and the executable on the Release/*.

So, my idea was to have several different targets, and use them like this:

```
all: maps auxiliars methods
    @echo "linking...";\
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(OBJS) $(CLIBS) -o ${OUTPUTPATH}/MainProgram

dependency1: $(INPUTPATH)/foo.cpp
    @echo "compiling ArbPrecision...";\
    cd ${BUILDPATH};\
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(CINCLUDE) -c ../$?

dependency2: dependency1 $(INPUTPATH)/bar.cpp
    @echo "compiling saddleConstructor...";\
    cd ${BUILDPATH};\
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(CINCLUDE) -c ../$(INPUTPATH)/bar.cpp

maps: dependency2 $(INPUTPATH)/*Map.cpp
    @echo "compiling maps...";\
    cd ${BUILDPATH};\
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(CINCLUDE) -c ../$(INPUTPATH)/*Map.cpp
... (auxiliars and methods)
```

The $CINCLUDE and CFLAGS are just compiler stuff like headers and external libs.

Everything works almost perfect: on every target, it asks for other target's dependencies, and for the *cpp on the source. If this does not exist, it calls the target and compiles the *cpp. The executable is created without errors.

However, if I call the "make" twice, the time it takes to compile is the same for the first and second time, even if I don't make any changes on the source. So, apparently, I'm not putting the dependencies right.

Can anyone point me the right direction to perform this compilation? I'm doing something wrong and I'm not getting what it is.

Thanks,
Jorge

Comment: When you compile the input is a source file (i.e. a .cpp file) and the output is an object file (normally a .o or .obj file). That is where you dependencies are supposed to be. You should be saying that bar.o depends on bar.cpp, etc. Similarly the linking step, your program depends on a bunch of object files, so they should be isted in the dependemcies for `all`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make expects to operate off of *files*.  For each rule, it checks to see if the target *file* named by that rule (1) exists and (2) is up to date (i.e., modified after any of its dependencies).  If the file is not up to date, then it executes the rule to bring it up to date.

Therefore, as your makefile is currently written, when you run `make`, Make does the following:

- `all` is the first rule, so if you don't specify any arguments, make processes the `all` rule.
- No file named `all` exists, so the `all` rule needs to be executed.
- `all` depends on the `dependency1` rule.  No file named `dependency1` exists, so the `dependency1` rule needs to be executed.
- `dependency1` depends on the `dependency2` rule.  No file named `dependency2` exists, so the `dependency2` rule needs to be executed.

What you instead want is something similar to the following:

```
OBJS := foo.o bar.o Map.o

all: $(OUTPUTPATH)/MainProgram

$(OUTPUTPATH)/MainProgram: $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(OBJS) $(CLIBS) -o $(OUTPUTPATH)/MainProgram

%.o: %.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(CINCLUDE) $< -c $@

.PHONY: all
```

Note the following:

- Since Make operates on files, rules' targets and dependencies are listed by filename wherever possible.
- Rather than listing the .cpp files individually, an [pattern rule](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Pattern-Rules) is used to build each .o file.  Within the pattern rule, the `$<` and `$@` [automatic variables](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Automatic-Variables) are used to specify the first prerequisite (file) and the target (file), respectively.
- Make echoes its commands by default, so there's no need to `echo` yourself.
- For GNU Make, `all` is listed as a [phony target](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Phony-Targets), to keep Make from looking for a file named `all`.

Comment: The pattern rule must include the names of the directories: `$(BUILDPATH)/%.o: $(INPUTPATH)/%.cpp`

Comment: @anatolyg - Thanks.  I was oversimplifying paths, partly to focus on concepts, and partly because I was lazy.  :-)

Comment: Ok, that is a big difference... :p Why you've compile the objects with -o and the executable with -o? Isn't the -c for compiling and -o for linking?

Comment: @J.C.Leitão - Oops.  Fixed.  Thanks.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the explanation, I was thinking wrongly about it. Now I think I understood the underlying idea of makefile.